# how to extract text from a parsed html page in pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

consider this simple example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'link' : ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke',
                             'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World']})

df
Out[169]: 
                                                           link
0         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke
1  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World
```

I want to parse each link using `beautiful soup` and store the parsed content into another column of my dataframe. The following seems to work well:

```
def puller(mylink):
    doc = requests.get(mylink)
    return BeautifulSoup(doc.content, 'html5lib')

df['parsed'] = df.apply(lambda x: puller(x))
df['mytag'] = df.parsed.apply(lambda x: x.find_all('p'))
```

The issue is that I am getting lists and I need to work on the text inside them. In particular, I am trying to only keep the paragraphs that mention `joke` somewhere in the text but I am unable to do so.

```
def extractor(mylist):
    return list(filter(lambda x: re.search('joke', x), mylist))

df.mytag.apply(lambda x: extractor(x))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What is the best way to proceed here?

Thanks!

Comment: That is probably not the right use-case for explode. Also, you should elucidate the nature of `df['mytag']` by way of examples.

Comment: added some more info. thanks

Comment: simplified and clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pandas api is designed to be used on more primitive datatypes; you are better off writing a functions that converts link -> text you want and then calling `apply`.  Here is one solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame({'link' : [
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke',
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World'
    ]
})

def parse_link(mylink):
    doc = requests.get(mylink)
    return BeautifulSoup(doc.content, 'html5lib')

def matching_paragraphs(soup, text):
    res = [p.get_text() for p in soup.find_all("p") if text in p.get_text()]
    return res
   
def apply_func(link, text):
    soup = parse_link(link)
    res = matching_paragraphs(soup, text=text)
    return res
    

df['text'] = df.link.apply(apply_func, args=("joke",))
```

output:

```
                                                link                                               text
0  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funnie...  [The "world's funniest joke" is a term used by...
1  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  ["The Funniest Joke in the World" (also "Joke ...
```

More sensibly with a dataframe, you can convert the list of strings to rows:

```
df.explode(column="text", ignore_index=True)
```

result:

```
                                                 link                                               text
0   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funnie...  The "world's funniest joke" is a term used by ...
1   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funnie...  The winning joke, which was later found to be ...
2   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funnie...  Researchers also included five computer-genera...
3   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  "The Funniest Joke in the World" (also "Joke W...
4   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The sketch appeared in the first episode of th...
5   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The sketch is framed in a documentary style an...
6   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The British Army are soon eager to determine "...
7   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The German version is described as being "over...
8   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The Germans attempt counter-jokes, but each at...
9   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The British joke is said to have been laid to ...
10  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  The footage of Adolf Hitler is taken from Leni...
11  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Jok...  If the German version of the joke is entered i...
```

Answer (score 1):

Each entry of `df[mytag]` is a *list of beautifulsoup `'<p>'` elements*. You could write a function that takes this list and return the text that contains your word. Then use `.apply` over `df[mytag]` to have it work on all your rows.

```
def myfunc(list_of_ps, word='joke'):
    '''
    This will return a list of string text paragraphs 
    containing the word.
    '''
    result_ps = []
    for p in list of ps:
        if word in p.text:
            result_ps.append(p.text) # p if p itself is needed

    return result_ps if result_ps else None

df['mytag'].apply(myfunc)
```

**Edit:**
The error in your question reflects the fact mentioned in italics above. re.search expects strings as parameters. In other words, `x` in that function call needs to be a string or a byte-like object. In this case, it is a BeautifulSoup object as an individual `<p>` element. The error can be resolved by getting the string text of the element as `x.text`.